# How to escape <, >, and & characters to html entities in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: html, oracle, plsql, escaping, html-escape-characters

I need to send HTML emails directly from oracle PL/SQL package. This works almost fine.

I have problem with the fact that some of the data fetched from a table contain things like `<S>`, `<L>`, and similar fragments, which sometimes ar treated as HTML tags, and even if not, they are always ignored and never displayed.

So, I need to escape this column before inserting into email body.

Is there a function to escape html special chars into entities automaticly? 
Or do I need to `replace('<', '&lt;', string)` manually all the special characters?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the htf.escape_sc function:

```
SQL> select htf.escape_sc('Please escape <this> tag') from dual;

HTF.ESCAPE_SC('PLEASEESCAPE<THIS>TAG')
------------------------------------------------------------------
Please escape &lt;this&gt; tag
```

Answer (score 10):

Also available is DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT which can handle a clob.

Example:

```
select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT('<foo>') from dual
```

Details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm

Comment: Also note that this function returns a CLOB (per details in link provided).

Comment: No, it returns a CLOB if you pass a CLOB, or a VARCHAR2 if you pass a VARCHAR2. This example returns a VARCHAR2.