# converting code to symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, symbols

I'm using system to control the process in my company and some of it has comment table, let us say it is Opr_comm. the content inside that attribute is various sometimes it contain "<", ">", "'" and so many symbols. here is the query.

```
SELECT
    T1.Prod_No, 
    T1.Proc_CD,
    T1.Opr_Comm
FROM
    P110 T1
```

I have figure it out, when we input to system `<` it will turned to be `&lt`, when `>` it will be `&gt`. it happen when i retrieve it from database.

So, how can i convert that code to be symbol again?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053090/how-to-escape-and-characters-to-html-entities-in-oracle-pl-sql

Comment: to be honest i dont understand what they said in that question thread --"

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to convert back to symbols when you are reading from the table, and not during the write process, you can use the REPLACE function

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm

It's bulky, but if this is a limited issue it will work.  You'd replace your code:

```
SELECT
T1.Prod_No,
T1.Proc_CD,
replace(replace(T1.Opr_Comm,"&lt;","<"),"&gt;",">") AS Opr_Comm
From
P110 T1
```

Of course if you're able to prevent this encoding from happening in the first place, you'd be better off.