# I have a clob with HTML document. How to replace all scripts in it with text?

Tags: html, oracle

for example I have the following HTML document:

```
<b>Hello world</b>
<script>window.alert('Hello world')</script>
```

And I need to to get:

```
<b>Hello world</b>
&lt;script&gt;window.alert('Hello world')&lt;/script&gt;
```

I want to write an Oracle PL/SQL function that will make such conversion.

I use Oracle 11. I tried using regexp and Oracle XML functions but unsuccessfully.

Comment: For a clob, try DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663607/3061852

Comment: Thank you kfinity. The problem is that only content of <script> tag needs to be escaped.Now I added <b> around 'hello world'  to show it. This <b> tag needs to be left uncahnged

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the (built-in) REPLACE function. Example (tested w/ Oracle 11g, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5ab5da653dd4c93ea1d4313da658a66)):

**Table for testing**

```
create table myclobs ( col clob ) ;

insert into myclobs ( col )
values ( '<b>Hello world</b><script>window.alert(''Hello world'')</script>');

select * from myclobs ;

-- result
COL
<b>Hello world</b><script>window.alert('Hello world')</script>
```

**Query**

```
select
  replace( 
    replace( col, '</script>','&lt;/script&gt;' )
  , '<script>','&lt;script&gt;' 
  ) as scripttagsreplaced
from myclobs ;

-- result
SCRIPTTAGSREPLACED
<b>Hello world</b>&lt;script&gt;window.alert('Hello world')&lt;/script&gt;
```

( The "inner" REPLACE converts the end tags, and the "outer" REPLACE converts the start tags. )  If this works for you, and you still want to write your own function, just compile the following:

```
-- rst: Replace the Script Tags
create or replace function rst( theclob clob )
return clob
is
begin  
  return  replace( 
    replace( theclob, '</script>','&lt;/script&gt;' ) 
  , '<script>','&lt;script&gt;' 
  ) ;
end ;
/
```

With this in place, you can SELECT ... as follows:

```
select rst( col ) from myclobs ;
```