# I want to replace '&' character with '&amp;' in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is special requirnment this result they want to use for there deployment .please find all ddl and dml commands with my trials

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  my_column VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES ('Apples & Bananas');

SELECT REPLACE(my_column, '&', '&amp;') AS modified_column
FROM my_table;

SELECT REPLACE(my_column, CHR(38), '&amp;') AS modified_column
FROM my_table;
```

Please suugest a sql query which will give result

Output I am getting:

```
MY_COLUMN
Apples & Bananas
```

Output I want:

```
MODIFIED_COLUMN
Apples &amp; Bananas
```

Comment: Your both the query should return what you want.

Comment: I think your problem is the tool you are using to display the output is parsing your output and rendering `&amp;` as the XML entity `&`

Comment: I wonder if actually, the problem is that `&` is the default for a substitution variable and that's what's causing problems for your deployment? If so, perhaps a simple `set define off` in your deployment scripts would do the job, or maybe changing the default character from `&` to something else that isn't likely to be in your tables, e.g. `set define ~`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape <, >, and & characters to html entities in Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053090/how-to-escape-and-characters-to-html-entities-in-oracle-pl-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Your target character `&` and replacement `&` are the same thing.  The replacement should be `&amp;`:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(my_column, '&', '&amp;') AS modified_column
FROM my_table;
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y573NDJh).

But really you shouldn't be doing HTML escaping this way.  Rather, use a programming language which has a proper HTML escaping function, such as JavaScript or Python.

Answer (score 0):

replace should work OK.

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> CREATE TABLE my_table
  2  (
  3     my_column   VARCHAR2 (100)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO my_table (my_column)
  2       VALUES ('Apples & Bananas');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM my_table;

MY_COLUMN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apples & Bananas

SQL> UPDATE my_table
  2     SET my_column = REPLACE (my_column, '&', '&amp;');

1 row updated.

SQL> SELECT * FROM my_table;

MY_COLUMN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apples &amp; Bananas

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(my_column, '&', '&amp;') AS modified_column FROM my_table;
```

as your current and replace characters are same '&'. So, use '&' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate '&' in the String value like:

```
SELECT REPLACE(my_column, '&', '&'||'amp;') AS modified_column
FROM my_table
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hcRu.png)